# Aplicações Android, quais vantagens e desvantagens das ferramentas?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, xamarin

Entre criar apps nativos, usar HTML, CSS e JavaScript juntamente com Phonegap, ou ainda C# com a ajuda do Mono, quais são as vantagens e desvantagens e qual contexto melhor se aplica?

Considerando os seguintes itens:

- Performace
- Design da aplicação
- Manutenção da aplicação
- Acesso aos recursos do dispositivo

Comment: @bigown se fosse uma questão entre "apps nativos x apps webs" reduziria o escopo certo?

Comment: concordo com você @bigown reli minha pergunta e pedi opiniões no chat, ela estava bem complexa mesmo. Com a edição gostaria de comprar o app nativo, PhoneGap e Xamarin.

Comment: Não sou bom pra escrever respostas complexas e explicativas kkk mas olha que bacana aqui nesse site: http://www.luisaambros.com/blog/diferenca-entre-aplicativos-nativos-hibridos-e-mobile-web-apps/

Comment: obrigado @DiegoFelipe esse link é muito útil!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jedaias, vou responder com base no meu conhecimento e no que eu já desenvolvi com cada tecnologia.

Acredito que mais gente na comunidade possa contribuir com essa pergunta. Vejo que essa pergunta é muito realizada por quem esta começando e em alguns casos pode te levar a fazer uma escolha errada.

Primeiramente **é muito relativo o que você quer saber.**

Cada tecnologia ou método de desenvolvimento citado por você tem as suas vantagens, desvantagens e aplicações específicas, ou seja, depende muito do que você quer fazer para que eu possa te dizer se esse ou aquele é melhor.

O que vai te direcionar melhor é saber exatamente o que você quer fazer na sua aplicação, antes de tudo pergunte a si mesmo:

1. A sua aplicação vai rodar localmente ou na núvem?
2. A sua aplicação necessita de muitos recursos do dispositivo?
3. Sua aplicação é multiplataforma (Android, WP e IOs)?

Eu particularmente não gosto de nenhuma nem do Phonegap e nem do Xamarin (ou Mono, ou qualquer coisa parecida), isso é uma opinião e não quer dizer que estou certo, mais eu sempre acreditei que nada supera o desenvolvimento nativo, mesmo que seja mais trabalhoso e que a manutenção seja mais cara, o desenvolvimento nativo é bem mais seguro do que a utilização de ferramentas de interpretação e intermediação de código fonte.

Agora uma ideia sobre cada opção:

***Desenvolvimento Nativo:***

- É mais trabalhoso e caro, pois se a sua aplicação vai ser 
  multiplataforma, você terá que aprender cada linguagem e adquirir as ferramentas necessárias para cada plataforma;
- Se o desenvolvimento for realizado utilizando boas práticas e aproveitando o melhor de cada linguagem, com certeza terá uma performance acima da média;
- Você terá acesso à todos os recursos do dispositivo.

***Phonegap, HTML, CSS, Cordova, etc...***

- Empacota aplicações Web em um pacote que pode ser instalado nos equipamentos;
- É uma boa para aplicações Web que não necessitam de muitos recursos do equipamento;
- Fornece suporte há algumas funcionalidades nativas do equipamento;
- Possibilita o desenvolvimento multiplataforma, pois você escreve um código apenas e gera arquivos binários para diversas plataformas;
- O desempenho não é o forte desta abordagem, mais é possível desenvolver muita coisa legal;

***Xamarin, Mono***

- São interpretadores de código que convertem o que você codifica em C#, Delphi, etc... para que possa ser interpretado como linguagem nativa da plataforma desejada;
- Num projeto utilizando essa abordagem, você tem uma área que é compartilhada (Shared) entre todas as plataformas e uma parte específica para cada plataforma, ou seja, o desenvolvimento é multiplataforma, mais possui algumas partes que são específicas para cada plataforma;
- Devido ao item acima citado, além de ser uma abordagem que possibilita o desenvolvimento multiplataforma, possui um acesso maior aos recursos nativos de cada sistema operacional;
- Quando compilado possui um desempenho mais próximo do desempenho de uma aplicação nativa.

Basicamente é isso, e acredito que isso possa ser um embasamento inicial para que você possa escolher o que é melhor para você. Então com base no que eu repassei e nas perguntas que fiz no começo, abaixo lhe repasso a minha idéia:

1. Minha aplicação não é multiplataforma e preciso de desempenho máximo e acesso à todos os recursos do dispositivo: ***Desenvolvimento nativo;***
2. Preciso de uma aplicação multiplataforma para rodar localmente, com base de dados, etc...: ***Xamarin, Mono, ou nativamente se preciso de um desempenho excelente.***
3. Minha aplicação não utiliza muitos recursos do dispositivo ou vai rodar em núvem: ***Phonegap, Cordova, HTML, CSS, etc...***

Espero ter ajudado. Juntando isso com o link que o DiegoFelipe repassou, acredito que vai ser muito útil.

Comment: "São interpretadores de código que convertem o que você codifica em C#, Delphi, etc... para que possa ser interpretado como linguagem nativa da plataforma desejada;" Huuuum?!?!?!

Comment: Na realidade, eu nem sei se essa palavra se aplica ao conceito, mais foi o que me veio à cabeça, pois na realidade o Xamarin, o Mono, pegam o que vc escreve em C# ou Delphi e converte para a linguagem nativa do sistema operacional. É o que eu entendi, mais se alguem tiver uma definição melhor, me passa  ai que eu coloco na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Bem vamos lá. Em primeiro lugar, esqueça mono, é algo pago e muito caro, da muita dor de cabeça para o desenvolvimento em várias plataformas e a documentação é muito pouca. 
Entre nativo e hibrido considerando os itens que você quer:

- Performace: Melhor no nativo
- Design da aplicação: Melhor no hibrido
- Manutenção da aplicação: Melhor no hibrido
- Acesso aos recursos do dispositivo: Melhor no nativo

Na base hibrido é muito mais produtivo e rápido para fazer qualquer coisa porem perde bastante em performace, caso você precise de algo rápido e de custo baixo e a performace não seja um fator crucial ele é a melhor escolha sem duvida, agora se você tem tempo de sobra e grana de sobra e a performace é algo fundamental o melhor é nativo. Muita gente para lançar rápido a app escolhe hibrido e depois quando ela cresce o suficiente em numero de usuários migra para o nativo.

Comment: Corrigido, valeu