# Quais são as diferenças entre Web App, Native App e Hybrid App?

Tags: terminologia, app

Sempre quando eu faço uma pesquisa a respeito de desenvolvimento mobile eu me depara com três termos que aparecem muito nas pesquisas.

Esses termos são:

- Web App
- Native App
- Hybrid App

E isto me gerou algumas dúvidas que eu gostaria de que fossem esclarecidas, as dúvidas vem logo abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é Web App?
2. O que é Native App?
3. O que é Hybrid App?
4. Quias são as diferenças entre Web App, Native App e Hybrid App?

Comment: Acho que não é a mesma, mas fica o link para relacionar:[Aplicações Android, quais vantagens e desvantagens das ferramentas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109080/28595)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Web App

Web App é a aplicação feita para **rodar em um *browser*** de internet normal. Ele pode até ser [SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123913/101), mas ainda será como um **website, usando HTML, CSS, JS, etc.** hoje pe JS não é tão necessário, tem opções), com todas limitações normais da web. **Não acessa os recursos privilegiados do sistema operacional**.

Ela costuma rodar bem em **várias plataformas**, com um pouco de cuidado. Há controvérsias, mas diz-se que é o mais barato quando deseja rodar em qualquer dispositivo. Fazer rodar em todos navegadores, em todos dispositivos, não é tão simples quanto pode parecer.

Você tem todas dificuldades de estar rodando em uma interface que você não tem total controle. A **usabilidade não a melhor possível** para a maioria dos casos, é a típica da web.

É interessante para quem será um **usuário bem eventual**. Ele **não precisa instalar** algo para rodar. Mas precisa saber o endereço (URL) onde está a aplicação e entrar no *browser*. Não espere que uma pessoa vá instalar um aplicativo para usar uma ou outra vez. As pessoas instalam bem poucos aplicativos nos seus dispositivos e só o fará se for muito útil ou ela seja muito fã daquilo.

## Native App

Native App é aquele é **usa os recursos nativos do dispositivo** de forma direta e tem acesso à tudo da melhor forma possível. Grosso modo podemos dizer que é como fazer a aplicação desktop que estamos acostumados. Por exemplo usando a Win32, ou alguma biblioteca que a acesse de forma mais ou menos direta.

Geralmente **roda bem em apenas uma plataforma**. Mas existem bibliotecas que ajudam rodar a mesma base de código com pouca adaptação em mais de uma plataforma mantendo a característica nativa. [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/), por exemplo. Aqui é só opinião mas tecnologias como o Xamarin faz o híbrido quase desnecessário.

**Costuma dar o melhor resultado em usabilidade**. Também costuma ser **o mais rápido**.

É um aplicativo de verdade.

## Hybrid App

Hybrid App é uma aplicação web geralmente rodando em um *runtime* específico, pode até ser um ***browser* personalizado** para isso e que permite **acessar recursos nativos** que normalmente não estão disponíveis no *browser* normal. É um aplicativo normal.

Claro que nada impede que uma aplicação híbrida seja feita em um modelo um pouco diferente, mas costuma ser assim.

As pessoas usam para tentar fazer uma **aplicação única rodar em várias plataformas sem tantas restrições**. Nem sempre dá tão certo quanto se espera. Depende do resultado buscado e orçamento disponível.

É uma solução no meio termo entre as anteriores. **O resultado é meio termo**:

- A usabilidade é boa, mas não é ótima.
- O desempenho não é o melhor, mas aceitável.
- Acessa os recursos do dispositivos, mas não da melhor forma possível e nem sempre tudo está disponível, pelo menos não imediatamente ao lançamento
- Consome mais recurso que nativo, incluindo bateria, porém menos que web.
- O trabalho não é tão grande quanto fazer nativo para cada plataforma, mas não tão pequeno quanto fazer um só para tudo.

## Conclusão

Pra mim tem duas opções. Web ou nativo, depende da intenção, do público.

Se for nativo, tem que escolher se vai atingir mais de uma plataforma. Lembre-se que o Android atinge a maioria do mercado, dependendo do público a ser atingido, 70, 80, ou até mais de 90% do mercado, e a fatia está crescendo. Fora ele praticamente só o iOS é usado de fato e tem crescimento absoluto não desprezível.

Muitos aplicativos serão usados para um público bem específico, provavelmente para funcionários de uma empresa que usam ou podem usar um dispositivo padronizado. Nem sempre precisa mais de uma plataforma.

Vai fazer para mais que uma plataforma? Aí a escolha é se vai fazer uma aplicação para cada uma delas, e isso tem lá sua vantagem, ou usar uma mesma base para todas elas (provavelmente duas, ou três no máximo).

Grosso modo vamos dizer que se os profissionais envolvidos dominam as tecnologias, fazer a aplicação nativa dá um resultado de 100%, fazer nativo com uma biblioteca de compatibilização dá 95, quem sabe 98%, mas pode ser só 90%, depende da qualidade dela, fazer híbrido, dá 70, 80%, e web uns 50%, claro que depende de cada caso. Não considere esses números como um estudo, é só minha percepção.

Se for feito certo, a codificação não pesa tanto no custo. Fazer para três plataformas não vai custar três vezes mais. Aproveitar código para as três não reduzirá o custo para um terço.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

**1. O que é Web APP?**

Web App, é uma aplicação desenvolvida utilizando tecnologias web (HTML5, CSS. JavaScript). Porém feita com o intuito de imitar ou ser muito parecida com um aplicativo Mobile utilizando técnicas de design responsivo, por exemplo. 
O termo também pode se referir a uma aplicação web (sem ter a intenção de ser parecida com um aplicativo Mobile).

Pros:

- Quem tem um browser pode acessar.
- Não precisa ser posto em uma Store( App Store, Play Store)
- Utiliza tecnologias altamente difundidas (HTML, CSS e JavaScript). O que dá maior facilidade de encontrar profissionais.

Contras:

- Não acessa certas funções do Sistema Operacional. O que pode dificultar a interação do usuário.
- O acesso ao aplicativo depende de um browser (certos usuários não gostam disso).

**2. O que é Native App?**

Esses app são os desenvolvidos utilizando as linguagens e bibliotecas de códigos disponibilizadas pela fabricante do sistema operacional. Por exemplo, para Android você usa Java, Gradle, Android Studio e as bibliotecas/APIS do android (import android).

Pros:

- Tem acesso as chamadas do Sistema Operacional
- Geralmente tem melhor desempenho do que outras soluções.
- Utiliza componentes de interface nativos o que ajuda na experiência do usuário.

Contras:

- Custo é bem alto para manter duas equipes, por exemplo, para Android e para iOS.
- Achar profissionais com as competências das duas ou de uma plataforma pode ser difícil.
- Manutenção é trabalhosa.

**3. O que é Hybrid App?**

O aplicativo híbrido é desenvolvido utilizando tecnologias Web assim como o Web App, porém não são para Browsers. Esses aplicativos são desenvolvidos para serem utilizados dentro de um WebView - Um componente de interface que existe em todos os ambientes mobile que interpreta JavaScript, Html e CSS-, por isso esse tipo de aplicativo consegue fazer chamadas ao Sistema Operacional e utilizar recursos do Hardware, como Câmera, acesso a arquivos para escrita e leitura.

Pros:

- Pode ser distribuído pelas Stores
- Só precisa de uma equipe para dar manutenção e implementar features.

Contras:

- Desempenho pode ser um problema dependendo da aplicação.
- Não acessa algumas chamadas do Sistema Operacional ou trabalha mal com elas.
- Dificuldade em manutenção, pois faz-se uso de várias bibliotecas para alcançar um comportamento parecido com o Nativo.

  **4. Quias são as diferenças entre Web App, Native App e Hybrid App?**

Creio que listei algumas acima, porém caso você queira se aprofundar tem alguns links (em inglês) abaixo:

[StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109167/hybrid-vs-native-mobile-app/11061354#11061354)

[Este link cita alguns pros e contras](http://howwedostartups.com/articles/Native-vs-Hybrid)

[Umas imagens bacanas](https://www.joshmorony.com/whats-the-difference-between-native-hybrid-and-web-mobile-app-development/)

[image: Diferença entre Native, Web e Hybrid Apps]

Answer (score -2):

Existem três tipos principais de aplicativos móveis: Web App, Native App e Hybrid App. Cada tipo tem suas próprias características e funcionalidades, e o tipo mais adequado para um projeto depende das necessidades e objetivos do desenvolvedor.

**Web App** é um aplicativo que é executado no navegador da web, como o Google Chrome ou o Safari. Ele é acessado através de um endereço URL e pode ser usado em qualquer dispositivo que tenha um navegador compatível. Web Apps são desenvolvidas com tecnologias da web, como HTML, CSS e JavaScript, e não precisam ser baixadas ou instaladas.

**Native App** é um aplicativo que é desenvolvido especificamente para um sistema operacional móvel, como o iOS ou o Android. Eles são baixados e instalados diretamente na memória do dispositivo, o que os torna mais rápidos e confiáveis do que as Web Apps. Native Apps também têm acesso a recursos do dispositivo, como a câmera, o acelerômetro e a localização, o que os torna mais poderosos e versáteis. No entanto, eles só podem ser usados em um dispositivo compatível com o sistema operacional específico.

**Hybrid App** é um tipo de aplicativo que combina elementos de ambos os tipos anteriores. Ele é desenvolvido com tecnologias da web, mas é embalado em uma "caixa" que permite que ele seja distribuído e executado como um aplicativo nativo. Isso significa que ele pode ser baixado e instalado como um aplicativo nativo, mas ainda usa tecnologias da web para sua interface do usuário e funcionalidade. Hybrid Apps têm acesso a alguns recursos do dispositivo, mas geralmente não tanto quanto os aplicativos nativos. Eles são uma opção intermediária entre Web Apps e Native Apps, e podem ser uma boa escolha para projetos que precisam de alcance mais amplo e acesso a alguns recursos do dispositivo.

Comment: Oi Ivan. É muito legal acrescentar novas respostas (o Area51 recomenda uma média de 3 por questão para que o site seja considerado saudável) mas fica a dica de sempre acrescentar algo útil novo. Não acho que seja o caso aqui, mas há discussões no nosso Meta e no Meta da rede que incentivam negativo em respostas "atrasadas" que repetem o que já existe. Que inovam, por outro lado, são sempre bem-vindas.