# Quais são as diferenças entre uma aplicação web e a aplicação desktop?

Tags: aplicação-web, terminologia, aplicação-desktop

Eu sempre faço confusão com aplicação web e aplicação desktop, não consigo entender muito bem a diferenças de ambas.

## Perguntas

1. Quais são as diferenças entre aplicação web e aplicação desktop?
2. Quais são as principais característica de cada um?

Comment: https://bitmasters.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/sistema-web-x-sistema-desktop/

Comment: Eu tinha dúvidas se essa pergunta era boa, mas fui pesquisar e não só é interessante e útil, como acho que vai bombar, esta é uma demanda de muita gente.

Comment: Nunca pensei no seguinte, mas acho que é cabível: pode uma aplicação desktop também ser web? Por exemplo sistemas que informam ao usuário que o mesmo esta desatualizado, de alguma forma checam em algum lugar na rede. Ou, ainda, sistema que necessitam de um crack para funcionar.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio geralmente se usa web como definição de "coisa rodando no browser". Mas nada obriga que uma aplicação desktop tenha o servidor na rede local. Uma das vantagens de TCP/IP nesse cenário é que pode ser hibrido, só local, só remoto se usar rede.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio estou vendo se acho informações confiáveis que determinem esse limite. Eu estava pensando: se uma aplicação é essa típica de desktop mas consome tudo de um webservice ou algo assim, faz dela uma aplicação web? Eu acho que não, mas quero certeza, espero obtê-la ao final do processo de pesquisa.

Comment: Como diria o Silvio: Essa pergunta vale um milhão de reais.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## TL;DR

Aplicação web é aquela acessada pelo navegador (completo ou parte dele). Aplicação desktop é aquela acessada diretamente pelo sistema operacional (em um desktop, claro).

## Introdução

Quero deixar claro que fiz uma pesquisa razoável para poder responder da melhor forma possível, sem incorrer em opiniões ou informações dúbias. Mas não achei nada formal que defina bem o que caracteriza cada uma, é tudo vago e sem referências. É claro que algumas coisas são óbvias, mas muitas podem até parecer óbvias e nem ser uma característica inerente de cada plataforma.

Então não tome esta como uma resposta definitiva, ela é apenas um apanhado do que encontrei escrito e de observações pessoais tentando aplicar um método científico informal para identificar a definição que encaixa bem com o uso prático.

Pela baixa qualidade do conteúdo que encontrei tive que adotar mais uma postura de ir eliminando opiniões que claramente não se encaixam. Notei que há muitos mitos na definição dos termos e consideram uma das formas de fazer a aplicação como característica da plataforma, o que nem de perto é.

## Acertar termos

Acho que podemos incluir aplicações móveis dentro das aplicações desktop para este contexto, já que as aplicações tem objetivos e funcionalidades muito parecidas, o que muda é a plataforma de suporte e operação específica, embora cada uma tenha características diferentes. A diferença fundamental entre essas duas plataformas costuma ser apenas se o dispositivo fica em cima de uma mesa e tem tela grande ou fica na mão da pessoa e tem tela pequena, e provavelmente um uma entrada de ados com teclado virtual e indução na tela.

Uma [pergunta comparando web com mobile já existe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176771/101) e é uma discussão atual bastante frequente. E isso é relevante porque as mesmas características, vantagens e desvantagens do mobile X web podem ser usadas na comparação de desktop X web. No fundo o que estamos comparando é o nativo X web.

Aplicação desktop inclui notebooks, subnotebooks e até algum tablet mais completinho.

#### Aplicação servidora

São aquelas que rodam em máquinas específicas provavelmente de alta capacidade para ser um servidor para clientes externos. Na verdade uma aplicação servidora pode estar em qualquer máquina, até dispositivos móveis, ainda que menos comum, servindo clientes externos ou só aquela máquina. O que caracteriza esse tipo de aplicação é a falta de interação direta com usuário. A interação ocorre com outros componentes de software locais ou remotas.

Uma aplicação servidora se aproxima mais da forma de uma aplicação desktop, exceto pela interação, mesmo quando ela está servindo web.

Não falarei de servidor web porque acho que não é o foco.

## Características marcantes

Pelo que entendi as características que parecem haver mais convergência para definir o que é cada uma dessas duas aplicações são:

- a plataforma onde a aplicação roda
- a forma como a interação com o usuário ocorre
- onde a aplicação fica disponibilizada.

Existem outras, claro, mas não definem tão claramente o que é uma ou outra. Pelo menos não há consenso.

## Aplicações desktop

Podemos dividi-la entre as que usam uma interface gráfica, muito comum hoje, e as aplicações textuais (de console).

Existem outras classificações não tão relevantes para este contexto.

#### Características

Podemos chamar uma aplicação de desktop quando ela roda: a) diretamente em cima do sistema operacional; b) através de um software intermediário que não impõe restrições artificiais no acesso ao sistema operacional, tais como interpretadores embutidos na aplicação ou máquinas virtuais de linguagens.

O acesso se dá através de uma API específica da plataforma.

A plataforma fornece os meios de se programar essas aplicações da forma que melhor lhe convier. E aplicações bem desenvolvidas usam todo potencial da plataforma no máximo possível.

A interação com usuário se dá de forma esperada para aquela plataforma, pelo menos de forma aproximada. E não depende de nada além dela própria para completar a interação.

Ela deve obrigatoriamente ser colocada na máquina de alguma forma e ficar disponibilizada para uso ali mesmo (existe o acesso remoto que deturpa um pouco isso, não vou entrar em detalhes).

Pelo que entendi há a ideia de que se sua aplicação depende de outro software que funcione como uma plataforma para ele, a aplicação não pode ser considerada de desktop. Por exemplo se o acesso é feito por um terminal de acesso há um intermediário que invalida ela ser de desktop, ainda que o próprio software de acesso ao terminal seja uma aplicação de desktop.

#### Vantagens e desvantagens

Em geral essas aplicações tendem ser um pouco menos seguras para o usuário devido a sua pouca limitação. Ele deve escolher bem seus fornecedores de software.

Existem iniciativas para diminuir o risco com mais limitações e certificações de lojas de aplicativos. Nesse ponto a filosofia do mobile difere um pouco do desktop que costuma ser um pouco mais livre, mas não é limitação técnica, é imposição artificial.

A própria aplicação corre um risco maior de ser danificada pelo usuário porque fica exposta ao usuário.

O uso geral da aplicação desktop costuma ser mais confiável e seguro evitando interferências externas já que ela tem um certo isolamento e dificuldade de manipulação indevida.

Em geral ela pode usar melhores mecanismos de autenticação e autorização.

Mas a segurança pode ser boa ou ruim dependendo mais do programador do que da plataforma.

De forma geral a aplicação desktop não pode ser acessada por meios externos. Note que não estou falando do acesso à solução como um todo que é possível e não depende da parte do desktop.

A experiência do usuário pode ser muito boa. Grandes entradas de dados funcionam de forma suave. A interação costuma ocorrer sem enroscos ou esquisitices. Elas tendem a responder mais rápido.

Há uma pequena barreira para iniciar o uso da aplicação na primeira vez (trazer para a máquina, eventualmente instalar, configurar, etc.)

Ela consome e aproveita melhor os recursos da máquina. Isto pode ser bom ou ruim.

Você pode acessar equipamentos externos, todo o sistema de arquivos, quaisquer serviços disponíveis, interagir com outras aplicações que permitam isso, além de acessar 100% da API pública do sistema operacional. Só precisa autorizar o acesso à algum ou todos recursos uma única vez.

Algumas coisas são mais fáceis de desenvolver nela, mas dada a flexibilidade algumas podem requerer um esforço adicional.

Claro que tudo isso pressupõe que a aplicação foi bem desenvolvida. Há uma enorme quantidade de programadores que têm dificuldade de produzir bons resultados, mas não é problema da plataforma, é do programador. Especialmente programadores web costumam ter muita dificuldade em transitar no desktop, daí muitos optam por fazer web, mesmo quando é mais adequado fazer desktop.

#### Exemplos de aplicações

As mais óbvias são as aplicações de escritório como processador de texto e planilha, sistemas de negócios, utilitários de administração dos dados do computador, jogos, softwares educativos, e os que atendem necessidades específicas.

## Aplicações web

Pensei e pesquisei muito se uma aplicação cliente que usa tecnologias tipicamente adotadas na web seria uma aplicação web. Conclui que isso não identifica claramente o tipo de aplicação. A forma como a aplicação foi desenvolvida não pode determinar o que a aplicação é. Seu funcionamento interno indifere para esse tipo de classificação.

#### Características

Podemos chamar uma aplicação de web quando ela roda em cima do navegador web padrão ou através de um software que atinja todos os mesmos objetivos. O navegador impõe restrições ao acesso à máquina.

O acesso se dá pela API padronizada universalmente disponibilizada pelo navegador.

A plataforma fornece os meios de se programar essas aplicações da forma determinada pela [W3C](https://www.w3.org/). E aplicações bem desenvolvidas seguem estritamente estes padrões.

A interação com usuário se dá da forma esperada universalmente na internet, pelo menos de forma aproximada. E depende de pelo menos um acesso mínimo inicial externo usando protocolo HTTP. Em aplicações web puras a interação ocorre com duas aplicações: o navegador e a página.

Ela deve obrigatoriamente ser disponibilizada sob demanda pelo menos a primeira vez via HTTP (mesmo que não seja remoto).

Pelo que entendi há a ideia de que se sua aplicação não depende do navegador, mesmo que ela use HTML, CSS, JS, e outras tecnologias típicas web, a aplicação não pode ser considerada de web. Se o acesso, mesmo externo por HTTP, é feito por uma aplicação de desktop que não é equivalente ao navegador não é uma aplicação web.

Por exemplo Node e Deno podem ser usados para aplicações não web.

#### Vantagens e desvantagens

Em geral estas aplicações tendem ser um pouco mais seguras para o usuário devido a sua limitação, até porque qualquer acesso fora do navegador deve ser autorizada individualmente pelo usuário. Ele deve pode acessar até o que ele não conhece ou confia muito.

A aplicação corre um risco maior de ser modificada pelo usuário, por isso não se pode confiar no que ela emite.

O uso geral da aplicação web costuma ser menos confiável e seguro já que está vulnerável a interferências externas e interceptações.

Mas a segurança pode ser boa ou ruim dependendo mais do programador do que da plataforma.

De forma geral a aplicação web não precisa acessar por meios externos, seja internet ou intranet, a não ser na sua carga inicial. Note que hoje não é tão comum aplicações web rodarem principalmente *offline*, mas isso tem mudado.

A experiência do usuário tende não ser tão boa. Grandes entradas de dados são bem prejudicadas. A interação costuma ocorrer com alguns enroscos e esquisitices. Elas tendem ter esperas, mas não é algo intrínseco à aplicação e sim a infraestrutura quase sempre usada.

A única barreira para iniciar o uso da aplicação na primeira vez é ter uma conexão externa para adquirir a aplicação, além de ter o navegador, óbvio. A não ser que ela seja totalmente local, o que é menos comum.

Ela consome e aproveita melhor a capacidade de interação com o mundo externo. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim.

Você **não** pode acessar equipamentos externos, o sistema de arquivos, quaisquer serviços disponíveis, interagir com outras aplicações, e só a API web disponível naquele navegador pode ser acessada.

Não é simples desenvolvê-la a não ser que seja para rodar na intranet e possa controlar o navegador que a pessoa usará (o que é irônico porque se fizer isso, a aplicação web perde quase toda razão de existir). O programador tem pouco ou nenhum controle sobre o ambiente.

Claro que tudo isso pressupõe que a aplicação foi bem desenvolvida. Há uma enorme quantidade de programadores que têm dificuldade de produzir bons resultados, mas não é problema da plataforma, é do programador.

#### Exemplos de aplicações

Se considerarmos que websites não são exatamente aplicações temos a utilização de softwares colaborativos em geral, aplicações de uso eventual por terceiros e ainda quando o acesso precisa ser feito de qualquer lugar de forma simples, além de outros softwares que imitam o que aplicações desktop fazem, obtendo diversos graus de sucesso ou insucesso.

Muitas aplicações são web porque havia um requisito não técnico que determinava assim.

## Quando adotar cada uma

Se é uma aplicação que o usuário usará com frequência, talvez diariamente, não tem dúvida que o desktop (ou mobile) é a opção mais adequada. Pode ter alguma exceção, mas tem que ter uma justificativa muito boa. Aplicações muito colaborativas **podem** acabar sendo úteis como web, mesmo em uso extremo.

Se o acesso do usuário será eventual e ele não terá uma ligação forte com a aplicação, vai de web.

## Controvérsias

Nem todo mundo concorda, nem todos conseguem perceber todas características que precisam ser analisadas e quais cada plataforma possui. Há muita informação falsa que foi disseminada na internet e como poucas pessoas produzem conteúdo original e a maioria só repete o que alguém escreveu, a informação se tornou ubíqua. Por isso eu entendo que muitas pessoas compram mitos sobre ambas.

Na outra resposta há alguns pontos que não parecem definidores desses tipos de aplicação, alguns talvez só que não é totalmente assim, outros não é o exposto, até mesmo pode ser o oposto.

#### Web

> Depende de conexão com a Internet;

Só para o acesso inicial, essa caraterística não é obrigatória, ainda que seja muito comum acessar assim.

> Não exige permissões para executar;

Exige para fazer operações específicas. O usuário tem que autorizar individualmente qualquer acesso que vá além do navegador.

> Usuários sempre utilizam a versão mais atualizada;

Se ela for obrigatória ser *online*. E isso obviamente não inclui o navegador que pode estar usando uma versão bem antiga que você deve suportar.

> Permite facilmente medir o que os usuários estão fazendo;

Assim como o desktop, com até mais medições possíveis.

> Geralmente exige conhecimento em diversas tecnologias para desenvolvimento, como CSS, JavaScript, HTML, Back-end;

Isso não importa para aplicação.

#### Desktop

> Funciona mesmo sem conexão com a Internet;

Algumas, já outras exigem internet, assim como uma aplicação web. Só porque a aplicação é desktop não quer dizer que ela não possa acessar dados pela internet ou até mesmo acessar webservices. É possível, mas em geral ela não acessa páginas normais web.

> Possui tamanho de tela pequeno, não sendo uma boa prática o uso do scroll;

Em geral a tela visível é maior que web que tem um espaço consumido pelo navegador. Dá para usar *scroll* sem problemas, o programador deve escolher o que faz mais sentido para aquela aplicação. Assim como web não precisa usar *scroll* se ele não quiser.

> Requer permissões de administrador para executar;

Não requer, a não ser que faça alguma coisa específica que exige esse privilégio, assim como a web exige autorização para fazer certas tarefas que são triviais no desktop.

> Geralmente requer instalação;

Circunstancial. É opção do programador exigir uma instalação.

> Dificuldades para manter atualizado em todos usuários;

Não é verdade. Pelo menos não por culpa da plataforma, pode ser pela incapacidade do programador.

> Segurança e transferência de dados não são tão preocupantes, visto que executa localmente;

Muda muito pouco. O fato de ser local e ser desktop nada tem a ver, são características ortogonais. Transferências podem ser tão inseguras quanto web.

> Geralmente exige conhecimento de apenas uma tecnologia para desenvolvimento, como Java Swing, Delphi;

Não é bem assim, em geral precisa saber algumas tecnologias entre SQL, XML, JSON, algum XML-like específico, talvez para definir a UI, algum *script*, entre outros.

## Conclusão

Não posso afirmar que consegui responder de forma definitiva o que é cada um e estou disposto a melhorar se alguém encontrar alguma inconsistência.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: `Dificuldades para manter atualizado em todos usuários`: Porque é que isso nao é verdade? Eu concordaria que é bem mais simples garantir que um cliente está a usar a última versao da aplicacao se ela for uma aplicacao web. É claro há algumas situacoes onde isso nao é bem assim, mas essa nao é a regra. Toda a gente usa a última versao do stackexhange, facebook, google... etc

Comment: A aplicação deskttop pode se autoatualizar sem intervenção de ninguém, podendo inclusive optar se vai rodar uma versão mais velha se o usuário não quiser optar ou só rodar se estiver a versão mais nova, que é algo um pouco difícil de fazer por web. O fato de muita gente não fazer ou não saber como fazer não significa que não pode, ou sequer que é mais difícil atualizar. No máximo pode dar um pouco + de trabalho inicial, depois fica mais fácil porque um sistema operacional tem uma API muito estável, a web não.É um parto garantir que o seu site sempre funciona nos milhares de browsers diferentes

Comment: Certo mas está a misturar vários conceitos aí. `Dificuldades para manter atualizado em todos usuários` estamo-nos a referir em ter a última versao e nao versoes diferentes do software. Também nao é facil garantir que uma aplicacao desktop funciona em todos os sistemas operativos. O que nos leva ao ponto que sobra. Enquanto as aplicacoes desktop normalmente necessitam de desenvolvimento adicional para garantir que o software está na última versao, a aplicacao web nao necessita.

Comment: Aplicação web precisa funcionar em vários browsers, senão no máximo ela usa tecnologias tipicamente usadas na web, mas não é web, aplicação desktop só precisa rodar em OS diferentes por um requisito específico. Mas aplicação desktop não necessita desenvolvimento adicional para garantir que funciona em toda situação que ela não tem controle. Se fosse falado que atualizar desktop precisa de um desenvolvimento adicional, eu entenderia. Ainda ainda a diferença é mínima e só feita uma vez, não tem que ficar acertar em cada atualização como ocorre na web.

Comment: Eu já trabalhei em empresas que faziam aplicacoes web que só garatiam compatibilidade com o internet explorer. Era o browser usado pelos clientes... Eu diria que a partir do momento em que suporte o browser mais usado, ou browser usado pelos seus clientes, suportar outros browsers é um requisito especifico, tal como rodar em OS diferentes. Ainda se ve sites a anunciar a compatibilidade com uma lista de browsers, eles listam os icones dos browsers que suportam.

Comment: Então era aplicação para IE, não para web. E só uma versão do IE, porque quando atualiza o IE, quebra um monte de de coisa. Web pressupõe universalização, alias esse é o maior motivo para se fazer web.

Comment: um PWA, após a "instalação" na plataforma, é uma aplicação web ou desktop?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam as coisas começam ficar confusas, mas de forma geral tendo a achar web. Ainda não entendi totalmente o processo de PWA para afirmar alguma coisa concreta.

Answer (score 11):

Aplicação Web - É uma aplicação que roda hospedada na web. O core da aplicação deve rodar no servidor web, que é uma máquina diferente da máquina onde o usuário interage, que é a máquina cliente. Utiliza a arquitetura cliente-servidor através de requisições utilizando o protocolo http. 
O cliente é a máquina que acessa o servidor através de um browser e o servidor é a máquina que provê o serviço. A aplicação web em geral se utiliza de tecnologias que renderizam o conteúdo no browser, tais como html, css e java-script.

Aplicação desktop - É uma aplicação que roda na máquina do usuário, é um software compilado que utiliza os recursos do sistema operacional onde está sendo executado. Não tem que ser necessariamente um software instalado, embora grande parte seja. Roda através da chamada a um arquivo executável. Pode se comunicar com a internet ou não para executar algumas tarefas. Existem jogos que mesmo sendo aplicativos desktop só funcionam com conexão à internet, como é o caso de todos os jogos que rodam na plataforma Steam. A diferença é que o core da aplicação desktop encontra-se na máquina do usuário.

Comment: A definição da web não é bem isso, há suposição que o mais comum define o todo.

Comment: Sucinta e correta a resposta. Excelente!

Comment: Uma aplicação python(ou em qualquer linguagem funcional dá época da resposta) pode ser uma aplicação desktop interpretada ou compilada.

Answer (score 1):

Meu conceito sucinto e objetivo é:

**Aplicação Web** - Todo sistema que você acessa utilizando o browser, seja ele no seu computador de mesa, celular ou tablet. Ex. O site do seu banco.

**Aplicação Desktop** - Todo software que, para que você possa usar, você precisa de um computador de mesa que possua recursos de hardwares avançados ou de última geração, por exemplo, processadores de alta performance, processadores de vídeo, áudio e etc. Estes softwares geralmente não rodam em dispositivos de menor capacidade (celulares, tablet e etc) Ex. 3D Studio Max (Software de modelagem e renderização 3D).

Comment: A parte da web é uma boa definição, apesar de ser uma simplificação, a de desktop parte de uma premissa errada ou pelo menos está escrita de uma forma um pouco confusa.

Comment: Posso desenvolver um programa portátil, dessa forma ele não se enquadra em "precisa instalar", ele é Web ou Desktop?

Comment: Nem desktop e nem web, ele é um software portátil. Veja: https://softwareportatil.wordpress.com/software-portatil/

Comment: @LeoFraietta Boa resposta no comentário sobre o aplicativo mobile. Eles são um conceito mais recente que aquela classificação entre "desktop" e "web", e possuem um pouco de ambos. Já a sua definição de "aplicação desktop" está no mínimo atrasada pois hoje temos aplicativo web onde o browser vai consumir mais processamento e memória que aplicativos desktop, e temos dispositivos móveis com mais capacidade de processamento que computadores de mesa usados diariamente em grandes empresas.

Comment: Ok, concordo com sua observação @Caffé em gênero, numero e grau. Mas o o que eu queria era dar uma resposta sucinta e objetiva, portanto, o que eu queria deixar claro é que aplicações Desktop são utilizadas de uma forma diferente das aplicações web, sem gerar muita confusão. A melhor e mais completa resposta já foi dada então meu propósito era outro. O que tentei dizer dizer é que não faz sentido, ou talvez não é aplicável considerando seu apontamento, um aplicativo pesado de edição de 3D ou edição de vídeo, rodar em um dispositivo que não seja desktop na maioria dos casos.

Comment: @LeoFraietta inclusive considero a sua a segunda melhor postada até agora. Eu não positivei por causa da premissa errada, mas também não negativei. A outra que tem alguns votos tem vários erros, mas talvez tenha ganho porque tem um pouquinho mais de informação e um testemunho de que ela está correta, provavelmente só para me contrariar, comportamento já conhecido há bastante tempo.

Answer (score -7):

### Web

- Flexível, podendo ser acessada de qualquer dispositivo com browser;
- Depende de conexão com a Internet;
- Possui altura infinita de tela, sendo o scroll um recurso bastante usado;
- Não exige permissões para executar;
- Usuários sempre utilizam a versão mais atualizada;
- Permite facilmente medir o que os usuários estão fazendo;
- Requer maior preocupação com segurança e transferência de dados, visto que os dados trafegam na internet;
- Geralmente exige conhecimento em diversas tecnologias para desenvolvimento, como CSS, Javascript, HTML, Back-end;

### Desktop

- Funciona mesmo sem conexão com a Internet;
- Possui tamanho de tela pequeno, não sendo uma boa prática o uso do scroll;
- Requer permissões de administrador para executar;
- Geralmente requer instalação;
- Dificuldades para manter atualizado em todos usuários;
- Segurança e transferência de dados não são tão preocupantes, visto que executa localmente;
- Geralmente exige conhecimento de apenas uma tecnologia para desenvolvimento, como Java Swing, Delphi;

Alguns pontos são discutíveis, mas esta é uma visão geral.

Comment: Eu diria que todos os pontos são discutíveis, exceto os que estão errados ou pelo menos são *misleading*. Estou com pouco tempo hj, vou desenvolver mais o assunto, depois eu poderia falar de ponto por ponto. Eu ainda precisa acertar uns pontos na minha tb e confirmar algumas coisas que eu não tenho certeza se existe uma definição mais ou menos oficial ou bem aceita.

Comment: Tem muita coisa discutível aí mesmo. Boa parte dos pontos negativos do desktop só acontece em soft mal feito, e não limitação da tecnologia. A tela você faz como quiser no desktop e aproveita melhor que "web", se quiser pode fazer scroll infinito pra qualquer lado da mesma forma. É um eqúivoco sério achar que precisa de administrador, só soft mal feito depende disso para o uso normal (exceto serviços especiais, mas ai é outra coisa). Não tem dificuldade nenhum manter atualizado se for bem feito (e pode ser automático). Segurança não tem nada a ver com ser web, precisa de cuidados nos 2 casos

Comment: Em outras palavras, entendi o que você quer dizer, mas tem que entender isso como problema de programador e não da plataforma. Sei que dá essa impressão pra alguns, mas ai é mera questão de ter muita gente ruim no mercado (seja web ou desk). E sobre a web, eu poderia listar uma série de desvantagens que vc não pôs, como o fato de não ter acesso a dispositivos, depender de versão de browser para executar certas coisas se o app for moderno, de ser complexa a escrita de uma UI decente que chegue perto de um programa real, e assim vai (só comentando por cima, se fosse pra elaborar eu responderia)

Comment: @Bacco Pela experiência que tenho com apps desktop, este é sim um dos problemas recorrentes que passamos, inexistentes na web!

Comment: @MurilloGoulart sim, isso eu entendi perfeitamente. E realmente acontece muito, mas geralmente pq os caras programam mal. Eu teria casos e casos pra te contar disso acontecendo, e a maioria é falha de programador. Não tou discordando da sua percepção, só corrigindo o fato de não ser culpa da plataforma. Posso falar por mim mesmo, inclusive porque eu não só desenvolvo, como faço questão dos meus clientes não trabalharem como admin nunca.

Comment: Lembre-se que, caso interesse discutir o assunto (o assunto web x desktop, não o dos comentários), tem o chat da rede, a sala Estouro de Pilha é onde costumamos ficar. Vc já tem pontos de sobra pra participar com o pessoal. Tem bastante gente lá com experiência nas 2 áreas.

Comment: E antes que vc pense isso, esse negativo na sua resposta não é meu, apesar de eu discordar dela. Eu procuro sempre esperar um bocado pra dar tempo de todo mundo elaborar com calma.