# Como criar programa executável em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, .exe

É possível eu criar um programa pra minha empresa que seja executável, somente com PHP e MySQL? Ou vou precisar de outras linguagens, como C, Java, etc. No caso o programa é interno somente.

Comment: Utilize outra linguagem para essa tarefa. PHP não é a ferramenta mais adequada. Leitura **super recomendada:** [Qual é o conceito do GTK? É recomendável usá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133354/91)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Tem uma lista enorme de compiladores de PHP que geram executáveis. Muitos nem existem mais. O nível de qualidade deles é variável, e na prática "ninguém" usa. Alguns:

- http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard
- https://www.exeoutput.com/
- http://www.zzee.com/phpexe/
- http://www.phplockit.com/
- http://www.peachpie.io/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/bamcompile/files/bamcompile/
- https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop
- https://github.com/jaredallard/phc-win
- http://winbinder.org/
- http://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/
- https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger (.NET)
- https://github.com/facebook/hhvm (mas já estão portando para Hack)

Por que tem tantos? Porque nenhum presta :) Um tenta consertar o defeito do outro. Só não dou detalhes porque não é o foco.

Quer fazer uma aplicação "enterprise"? No mínimo pense em [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101) que foi criada para isto, mas nem tanto. Na verdade não use um martelo só porque acha que parafusos são parecidos com pregos, então ele seria uma boa solução. Escolha uma linguagem adequada para o problema, PHP é uma linguagem de *script*. E alguém negativou a resposta por eu dizer isso, parece "fla-flu" de Facebook onde a pessoa não quer enxergar o óbvio.

[image: Se você só tem um martelo todos os problemas parecem pregos]

Na verdade se o que está fazendo não é um *backend* web, nem pense em PHP. Se está pensando em uma aplicação em que web não é claramente a melhor solução, já escolheu o caminho errado. E a maioria das aplicações não são adequadas para web. É novamente o problema do martelo e dos pregos. [A pessoa só sabe usar o martelo, então ela acha que todo problema é um prego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument), ou seja, deve ser web, mesmo quando ela não dê vantagem significativa alguma e traz desvantagens. É o que eu vi esses dias sobre o [uso de modinhas, mesmo aquelas que duram décadas e sejam extremamente populares, e sobrepõe-se a necessidade do negócio pela vontade ou (in)capacidade do desenvolvedor](http://projetodraft.com/e-ridiculo-como-as-modas-digitais-se-tornam-um-paraiso-para-oportunistas-no-brasil-eis-a-verdade-sobre-elas/).

Para o que o PHP foi criado, ou seja, sites e aplicações que precisam ser web mesmo, desde que não muito complexos, aí não precisa de executável.

Como complemento, [não use PHP-GTK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133375/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu sei que meu comentário é inútil do ponto de vista dos parâmetros da plataforma, mas eu tinha que dizer que "não use um martelo só porque acha que parafusos são parecidos com pregos" virou um mantra agora.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda e o que seu comentário quer dizer?

Comment: É... Como meu comentário é ambíguo, é justo que eu diga que penso que é uma coisa boa :D

Comment: @ShutUpMagda esse é mais ambíguo ainda :D

Comment: nossa.. senhora.. do bit solto...

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto ?!?!?!

Answer (score 10):

PHP é uma linguagem interpretada, e não compilada. O objetivo dela não é gerar aplicações desktop, e sim pré-processar HTML.

Até é possível construir uma aplicação desktop com PHP (veja exemplos nas outras respostas), mas me parece uma baita de uma gambiarra. Se o seu objetivo é criar uma aplicação desktop, é melhor utilizar uma linguagem/framework que seja voltada para isso.

Outra coisa é que não sabemos muito bem o que você quer fazer. Se você tem um back-end com PHP e MySQL e um front-end web, transformar isso em "PHP executável" é jogar fora todo o front-end e refazê-lo. Por exemplo, quando te sugerem usar PHP-GTK, você teria que refazer toda a interface de usuário com GTK e jogar fora tudo que for HTML, CSS, JS. Será que é isso mesmo que você quer? Mais provável – e simples – é que você queira apenas embrulhar um front-end web como aplicação desktop. Pra isso tem várias ferramentas, como o [electron](https://electron.atom.io) e o [nw](https://nwjs.io/).

Comment: Entendi, acho que meu programa talvez funcione no navegador. Mas obrigado!!

Comment: Concordo plenamente com a resposta, mas caso tenha interesse, com tal framework/lib é possível criar apps p/ desktop com PHP. - http://gtk.php.net/

Comment: Depende do que ele entende como executável, pelo comentário dele talvez seja possivel criar pelo PHP, não será uma app Desktop, mas certamente será uma app "executável". :-)

Comment: @Sidon Somando o que ele diz no título e no post, acho que ele quer ambas as coisas: uma aplicação desktop compilada como executável.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Se quer usar tecnologia de web mas criar um executável, existem opções que são basicamente browsers programáveis, como o electron e o nw. Dá uma olhada neles, talvez seja o caso.

Comment: @bfavaretto, verdade. Outro dia usei uma solucao com uma webapp django, criei uma app no chome (um link de janela full sem endereço) os caras ficaram satisfeito. :-)

Comment: Desktop esta caindo em desuso, a não ser para situações muito específicas.

Comment: @Sidon ou seja, o marketing está vencendo a engenharia, certo? Estão fazendo aplicações horríveis, com inúmeras desvantagens, pra ganho zero ou próximo disto. Desktop não está caindo em desuso onde tem gente pensando sobre o problema e não seguindo a manada. As pessoas ficam satisfeitas com porcaria, por isso estão conseguindo vender web onde não cabe. Claro que web cabe em muita coisa, eu mesmo outro dia fui fazer algo que até aceitei uma aplicação ruim só pra não ter que instalar nada na máquina já que ia usar uma vez. Queria uma SO app p/ Windows, isso transcende web.

Comment: @bigown é a conversa que temos com frequência. Faz mais de 10 anos que muitos insistem que o caminho é aplicação no browser, e a realidade mostra o oposto, detonando esse discurso. Basta ver que praticamente toda aplicação séria para produção ou gerenciamento de conteúdo e dados é nativa ou desktop. Por exemplo, ERP e similares, um mercado onde os online competem nivelando por baixo, e até aplicações modo texto de 30 anos atrás muitas vezes são mais sérias do que vemos hoje online. Digo com tranquilidade que nos próximos 10 ainda vou poder sustentar a tese. Lembrei disso: http://bit.ly/2s7QuP5

Comment: @bigown, concordo em termos, eheheh, se a promessa de aplicações ricas tão propalada a uns 4 ou 5 anos atras se concretizasse eu até concordaria, mas sinceramente, acho que com as ferramentas disponiveis para desktop, somente para casos muito especificos

Comment: Complementando... Eu nunca concordo com "app ruim", seja web ou não. :-)

Comment: @Sidon você e qualquer pessoa tem direito de ter a opinião que quiser, mas e colocar duas aplicações bem feitas, uma GUI e outra web para os mesmos usuários, verá a diferença de produtividade e conforto de ambos. Note que sequer tem um argumento no seu comentário. De certa forma, se a aplicação não é adequada pra web e foi feita assim ela é ruim por definição. O problema é que quem fez acha que não é ruim, e não vai pensar diferente nem que provem pra ele que é pior.

Comment: Quero deixar claro que uma aplicação web rodando como desktop, ou seja, sem um browser web normal, até acho aceitável em muitos casos. è só uma GUI diferente, mas acaba tendo o *feel* desktop e acho que um dia pareará a qualidade da GUI nativa. Em browser normal, nunca chegará perto.

Comment: Certo @bigown, acho que nesse "board" ficaria dificil ficar argumentando, mesmo pq acho que fugiria às regras, mas o assunto é interessante, eu costumo dizer que na nossa área "certezas absolutas" não tem muita utilidade, por isso gosto do debate, se quiser podemos criar um chat sobre isso. :-)

Comment: @Sidon por isso que odeio essa certeza absoluta que a indústria adotou que web é melhor que desktop, sendo que tem estudos que mostram que não é a não ser nos casos que realmente é, mas todo mundo passou adotar web como padrão e dizer "desktop, somente para casos muito especificos", quando não há provas que isto deva ser feito, pelo contrário, há que isso não é o ideal. Debater é bom, não argumentar é ruim.

Comment: E nem se trata de pior ou melhor, e sim de adequado para cada situação. Exemplo: eu não gostaria de baixar um executável para interagir com uma aplicação que uso 2 vezes na vida para preencher 10 linhas de formulário, mas não gostaria de depender de um browser e internet para o meu cadastro de clientes que uso diariamente, durante todo expediente, principalmente se precisar instalar 200 plugins pra poder usar meus periféricos (é pior que baixar um executavel só). É a velha história, martelo se usa no prego, chave se usa no parafuso, faca se usa pra cortar queijo e não pra abrir gabinete de PC.

Comment: verdade seja dita: essa adoção de web por padrão começou pq quase todas aplicações desktop são ruins. Então tem que consertar o problema certo. O que fizerem é trocar de problema. Como todas aplicações web sofrem do mesmo problema, as pessoas foram aos poucos aceitando as deficiências e hj perderam a criticidade. Claro que ainda tem o problema que muitas aplicações web "que satisfazem os clientes" tem mais que o problema inerente da web, elas são absurdamente mal feitas e fracassariam retumbantemente há 20 anos atrás.

Comment: Eu ia fazer uma pergunta sobre quais os casos da aplicação web vs quais os casos da aplicação desktop, então encontrei essa pergunta (e suas respostas): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187344/64969; cc @Sidon

Answer (score -8):

**Resposta rápida**

1 - Pegue o PHP for Desktop e coloque um Wordpess com o plugin Sqlite, funciona até pra última versão 5.xx e pronto, terá um core fantástico como esqueleto.

2 - Utilize o Python para servir localmente os scripts PHP, simple.httpServer, depois através do pip instale o pyexec para gerar o executável na pasta escolhida dos scripts php, é tão fácil de usar que não há necessidade de maiores explicações, consiste basicamente em servir PHP com o servidor do próprio Python, desta forma você manipula texto, shell, bat etc, possibilidades infinitas, da pra controlar até mesmo o cooler.

**Não fale de tecnologias que não domina**

Não é apenas possível, é extremamente fácil. Não tenho tempo para fóruns, mas devido a tamanha ignorância e absurdos ditos nesta página, me senti da obrigação de desmentir esses DEVS ("programadores atuais de pc's da Xuxa agora se denominam Devs").

Criei não apenas um script, mais um sistema operacional hibrido completo me utilizando de PHP, PYTON, e SQLITE com empacotamento para Linux Debian com menos de 300 MB rodando tudo a partir do PHP for Desktop do Tom Czarek, o problema com o acesso físico e a linguagem de baixo nível, foi resolvido com PHP acionando o Python, melhor do que o mais avançado dos tristes Chromebooks, pois não há problemas com drives de vídeo, comuns em sistemas desse tipo, e que também afeta o PHP for Desktop, e então este último, basta utilizar Pywebview.

Perdoe o linguajar chulo, precisaria de muito mais do que um campo de comentários para explicar 25 anos de trabalho em tecnologias que poucos dão valor, ou sabem utilizar da forma correta ou de seu completo potencial, não sou saudosista nem torço para linguagem esta ou aquela, mas quando você percebe que pode fazer quase qualquer coisa com apenas Python e PHP, para quem deseja dominar verdadeiramente uma linguagem, este é o santo graal, pois se dedicar a diferentes frameworks e tecnologias, é condenar-se a ser mediano pelo resto da vida, o tempo vale muito mais do que isso.

Você não irá ouvir algo mais absurdo do que o PHP ser uma linguagem para a web, então Rasmus Lerdorf pensou, hora bolas, vou colocar essa função shell(shell_exec() & exec()) de enfeite, talvez um dia sirva para algo, a interpretação de CGI então, serve para fazer pão.

Quando uma pessoa diz que PHP não serve para fazer softwares robustos, ou é algum torcedor que trabalha de graça para frameworks, ou não tem a mínima ideia de como um computador interpreta comandos. Há sim algumas aplicações que podem ser mais adequadas do que o PHP por questão de facilidade e tempo de desenvolvimento, mas não por falta de capacidade de PHP em desempenhar semelhante tarefa.

Temos de aprender a dar mais valor a homens como Rasmus Lerdorf e a sistemas como o Linux, mais da metade deste fórum não iria ter como pagar uma licença de OS se o monopólio do software fosse como é o da web hoje para o Google.

Caso tenha dificuldade, posto um esqueleto pronto para que veja o funcionamento, tenha um bom dia.

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118406/discussion-on-answer-by-new-darma-como-criar-programa-executavel-em-php) e quem tiver interesse em ler ou acrescentar algo, pode clicar no link fornecido.