# Desempenho no PHP: considerar ou não?

Tags: php, desempenho

Vejo grandes conhecedores aqui do SOpt, dizerem a frase: 
***"Quer desempenho, esqueça o PHP"***

Por exemplo, perguntas sobre PHP:

"Como posso melhorar o desempenho disso?"

Claro que sabemos que "*desempenho*" vem muito da estrutura do código, mas essa afirmação "*Esqueça desempenho no PHP*", não seria pelo PHP não ter desempenho, mas sim porque é um fator a não ser considerado quando o cenário é o PHP em comparação de sua tecnologia com uma outra, correto!?

---

Então gostaria de saber:

- Acredito eu que, quando dizem que o PHP não se foca em seu desempenho, seria em comparação a outras linguagens/tecnologias?
- Isso seria sobre o PHP ser uma linguagem interpretada?
- Somente o PHP ou todas as linguagens interpretadas ou correlacionadas?

---

Entendendo melhor o tipo de resposta que eu gostaria, como no comentário feito:

> É dito isso porque o PHP não foi feito para ser rápido. Simples assim.
>   PHP foi criado para ser fácil e ter entrega rápida, abrindo mão da
>   performance, que em aplicações web, não é crítica. Se precisa de
>   performance não use PHP, assim como se precisar martelar um prego, não
>   use um alicate. – Anderson Carlos Woss

---

Antes de comentar ou responder, entenda:

**Não é "comparar qual a melhor linguagem" ou opinião, mas sim sobre a "diferença entre as tecnologias e/ou seus limites".**

Comment: Cara, vejo muita gnt falando mal do `PHP`, uso `PHP` a anos e nunca tive problemas com desempenho, certamente que existam tecnologias que tenham melhor desempenho, afinal esse é o intuito da evolução tecnologiaca, evoluir, pelo menos ao meu ver `PHP` tem mta vida pela frente ainda.

Comment: @WeesSmith Não é falar mau, é sobre o desempenho do php ser irrelevante sobre outras tecnologias (acredito eu, as compiladas). Mas claro que sempre terá o fator "sua necessidade", então o que é melhor para você, independe de tecnologia.

Comment: Quem sinalizou como "principalmente baseada em opiniões", a ideia não é opinião. É saber se realmente existe uma diferença de desempenho sobre a tecnologia do PHP em relação a outra. Principalmente pelo falo mesmo seria: "A melhor tecnologia é aquela que te atende". Só queria saber o motivo de dizerem isso, e não opiniões. Ou por favor, me diga porque considera ser opinião, pode ser que já resolva até a pergunta ! :)

Comment: Defina desempenho: Roda mais rápido mesmo em máquinas mais antigas ou é mais fácil de evoluir e dar manutenção ou mais fácil de produzir? De qq modo a qualidade do fluxo de trabalho e do código produzido impactam nisso talvez mais dq a tecnologia usada

Comment: A sua pergunta é muito ampla para obter uma resposta satisfatória e objetiva. Desempenho é a palavra mágica que as pessoas usam como determinante final para qualquer discussão sobre tecnologia, porém existem outros aspectos a considerar e cada situação é diferente. Coloque uma pergunta que tenha foco em algo específico e que possa ser comparado sem colocar a linguagem como um todo em julgamento.

Comment: @jean Dei um exemplo melhor na pergunta.

Comment: @Pagotti a pergunta seria sim muito ampla, mas foquei mais no "Por que dizem isso", "Por que não focar em desempenho no PHP", e pelo que entendi, é que por ser uma linguagem interpretada não se tantas alternativas como uma outra compilada, mas não que a linguagem seja ruim, pois nenhuma linguagem é.

Comment: So para mandar mais um pouco de lenha para a fogueira, a maior parte das questoes de "Como posso melhorar o desempenho disso ?" focam micro optimizações quase sempre irrelevantes para o cenário em questão. Coisas como "usar uma variável a mais ou não neste caso ou não ?"

Comment: @Isac Então Isac, mas essas afirmações de "Desconsidere foco em desempenho no PHP" é só no PHP ou em todas linguagens interpretadas ? É por ser interpretada que não tem tanta ênfase em focar no desempenho ?

Comment: Sugiro que troque este titulo, ta bem clickbait.

Comment: É dito isso porque o PHP não foi feito para ser rápido. Simples assim. PHP foi criado para ser fácil e ter entrega rápida, abrindo mão da performance, que em aplicações web, não é crítica. Se precisa de performance não use PHP, assim como se precisar martelar um prego, não use um alicate.

Comment: @Articuno eu nem sabia o que era "clickbait" até agora ! rs... Eu gostei do título do Woss, mas acho que fugiu. Veja

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É EXATAMENTE ISSO QUE EU QUERIA SABER !!! Mas só faltou dizer, se isso é mais com o PHP ou todas linguagens interpretadas, ou web no geral ?

Comment: @RBZ é difícil usar a palavra **todas**, mas, no geral, sim, as linguagens interpretadas possuem menor desempenho. O mesmo acontece com Python, por exemplo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss simples. Era isso cara. Se puder responder, para mim está respondido. É muito difícil fazer uma pergunta desse tipo, é difícil especificar o intuito da pergunta, deixando de fácil interpretação. Eu já esperava downvote, ampla demais, duplicada. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Particularmente, gostei da pergunta. Eu já tive essa dúvida antes, mas não perguntei por falta de coragem. kkkkk Valeu RBZ!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Estou aqui suando torcendo para não fechar ! rs

Comment: Se fecharem eu irei votar para reabrir, a sua pergunta é tecnica e não opinativa, a pergunta não é como tornar qualquer código rapido escrito em PHP (o que isto sim seria opinativo), mas sim entender o porque o PHP não é considerado rápido. (ps: pretendo dar uma resposta um pouco diferente das demais, assim que me sobrar algum tempo para poder criar um explicação o mais técnica possível, provavelmente ela será mais complementar).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Exatamente ! É praticamente: "Por que o desempenho no PHP não é tão considerado como em outras ? Por ser interpretado ?". E a "comparação" com outras linguagens, seria neste foco ! Com certeza ficarei aguardando sua resposta !

Comment: Aguardando ansiosamente a resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento... =) Geralmente são muito boas!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Eu entendi que estava falando de velocidade de execução. Então a resposta é que **não deve considerar o desempenho para micro-otimizações**.

[image: Otimização prematura é a raiz de todo mal]

Entenda que linguagens não possuem velocidade. No máximo elas têm filosofia que facilita ou não ter velocidade. Implementações já possuem um pouco mais. Mas nem tanto. Muitas vezes a performance está na biblioteca usada.

É possível algo pontual em PHP ser mais rápido que Java. Por que? Java tem poucos, mas alguns custos que uma linguagem mais baixo nível, como C, tem. Se uma função do PHP puder ser escrita em C, e muitas da biblioteca padrão são, e não tiver que ficar acessando muito a máquina virtual de execução do PHP, é possível que essa função consiga ser mais rápida, desde que a função seja muito bem escrita. Estou falando em tese, na prática não vejo isso ocorrendo muito.

É possível PHP rodar mais rápido e com [HHVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214519/101) pode melhorar. Hoje menos, porque a implementação de PHP melhorou muito. Tem várias ferramentas que ajudam. Mas ela tem outras questões que não podem ser resolvidas sem a linguagem se transformar em outra coisa. Em PHP 8 vai melhorar mais.

Aqui vai uma verdade cruel que muitos amadores de PHP (sim, eles amam a linguagem) odeiam ouvir: as pessoas envolvidas com o desenvolvimento da linguagem não são os melhores engenheiros do mundo, não possuem uma base teórica de linguagens muito adequada, e pegaram um legado complicado, fora que não possuem os recursos necessários para criar uma linguagem extremamente rápida.

Note que os *benchmarks* que mostram melhorias em PHP desconsidera a carga que piorou muito por fazer uma pré-compilação e otimização. Quando compara o todo, onde PHP é usado o todo é muito mais importante que em outros tipos de aplicação, o ganho não é tão grande assim. Nunca se esqueça que as pessoas que gostam ou produzem uma tecnologia vão usar medições que melhor atendem suas necessidades de *marketing*, o que é legítimo, só não perca isso de vista.

> Acredito eu que, quando dizem que o PHP não se foca em seu desempenho, seria em comparação a outras linguagens/tecnologias?

Sim, sempre tem que ser comparando com outras linguagens. Mas ninguém disse que PHP é a linguagem mais lenta que existe. E melhorou. PHP é mais rápida de Ruby (implementação padrão e atual), mais rápido em algumas coisas que Python, ganha em alguns pontos de Lua (embora LuaJIT já não costuma ocorrer), e perde feio para JavaScript (NodeJS para comparar com *backend*). Ela não chega perto em quase tudo quando a comparação é com C/C++, C#, Java, D, Rust, Delphi, Go, VB.NET, F#, etc.

> Isso seria sobre o PHP ser uma linguagem interpretada?

Um dos principais motivos. Mas também por ter **tipagem dinâmica** (provavelmente o maior motivo em execuções mais longas), por isso tudo tem que ser verificado internamente antes de executar. Algumas otimizações não são possíveis por causa disto, e por ser interpretada também.

Também por ter mecanismos *fit all*. Essencialmente não tem estruturas de dados diversos, tem o *array* associativo e serve para tudo. Até tem umas estruturas diferentes, mas são terrivelmente implementadas.

Tem uma série de decisões equivocadas que fazem a linguagem não ter o desempenho que poderia.

Pense que tem uma carga, uma preparação do ambiente e a compilação do texto para depois executar.

> Somente o PHP ou todas as linguagens interpretadas ou correlacionadas?

Todas que seguem a mesma filosofia. Não é possível bater a performance de um código gerado por um bom compilador e que "tudo" é resolvido em tempo de compilação.

É possível fazer linguagens interpretadas terem uma execução final bem interessante e em alguns casos até bater linguagens compiladas. Mas é extremamente difícil, custoso e quanto melhor for resultado de execução pior será o tempo de carga. Em execução de *script* isto tende a não compensar muito.

[Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101) é o PHP compilado e de tipagem estática, é muito mais rápido. Mas poderia mais se não quisesse manter boa compatibilidade com PHP.

> É dito isso porque o PHP não foi feito para ser rápido. Simples assim. PHP foi criado para ser fácil e ter entrega rápida, abrindo mão da performance, que em aplicações web, não é crítica. Se precisa de performance não use PHP, assim como se precisar martelar um prego, não use um alicate.

Concordo com a ideia geral, mas performance para web só não é crítica para coisas muito simples. O que faz todo sentido usar PHP. Mas não faz sentido fazer OOP com PHP.

Quando é algo de muito acesso, tem muito o que fazer, performance é crítico por custa mais caro manter infraestrutura que dê conta de algo mais lento. Pior ainda pode precisar soluções extremamente mais complexas para distribuir o trabalho, e isto custa muito caro. As pessoas nem percebem que estão pagando mais caro do que deviam. Ou que não precisam da tecnologia que estão usando.

Nem estou falando do custo de oportunidade que é perder um usuário porque demorou para responder.

> Esqueça desempenho no PHP

Obviamente isso vale pra micro-otimização. PHP se beneficia de ganhos macro. Escolher a forma de fazer pode dar ganhos interessantes.

> Por que não focar em desempenho no PHP

Porque o ganho será pequeno e o custo será enorme. A linguagem não ajuda ganhar desempenho e tem custo que não tem o que fazer que inda serão o grosso do tempo de execução. Em algumas linguagens é possível ganhar em 80, 90% do caminho do código. Em PHP costuma dar um máximo de 50, 60%, muitas vezes menos.

Também pelo fato que a maioria dos websites tem pouco acesso e não precisam desse ganho. Justamente por ter pouco acesso não compensa gastar muito com ele. Dar performance custa mais caro.

> um projeto que faz acesso a um banco de dados terá o tempo de acesso ao banco muito maior que o tempo de execução do código PHP

Isso nem sempre é verdade, especialmente em códigos PHP porque é comum o programador desta linguagem não entender todos os custos. Se ele fizer algo complexo em PHP que poderia ser feito no banco de dados, e vejo isto ocorrendo demais, em PHP custará mais caro que em C# ou Java.

Agora, uma questão importante é que PHP quase invariavelmente acessa banco de dados. Há outras linguagens que não. Quando não tem IO o ganho de performance é mais importante. De fato, IO gera um custo que faz ganhos de desempenho menos relevantes.

Pra resposta ficar completa preciso citar o comentário do Isac:

> a maior parte das questões de "Como posso melhorar o desempenho disso?" focam micro optimizações quase sempre irrelevantes para o cenário em questão. Coisas como "usar uma variável a mais ou não neste caso ou não?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Essa pergunta não podia ficar sua resposta. Só isso ! rs

Comment: Então, se por acaso eu precisar criar uma aplicação web que necessite de performance, o node.js, por exemplo, seria uma opção mais viável do que o php. É isso Maniero?

Comment: A comparação que eu fiz com acesso a banco de dados não é sobre comparar um código qualquer com outro mais otimizado (no PHP ou no banco), é sobre a preocupação com desempenho da linguagem A ou B com relação ao tempo de processamento do banco de dados. É mais no sentido que você colocou no I/O.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho a grosso modo sim, mas nem sempre um ganho de performance resulta em uma diminuição direta de custos, e a adoção de uma tecnologia a que você não está familiarizado, pode introduzir novos custos. Dê uma olhada neste benchmark: [ReactPHP vs Node.js](https://gist.github.com/nkt/e49289321c744155484c), sair de um cenario de 800 req/s para 3000 req/s vai realmente trazer uma ganho para a sua aplicação?

Comment: interessante @TobiasMesquita. Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso. Obrigado.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho tem que medir, mas pode ser mais rápido sim. Mas leia a resposta com atenção, não é tão simples

Comment: @AndreiCoelho. Ótimo benchmark, obrigado por compartilhar. Mas nos comentários há mais benchmarks, no caso utilizando o PHP 7. E há um salto de 4x mais req/s

Comment: @RafaelSimionatoHayashi na verdade não foi eu que compartilhei. Mas eu vi esse que você está falando. Realmente tem uma biblioteca do php que é muito boa.

Comment: @RafaelSimionatoHayashi o único problema é que está comparando maças com laranjas. A maioria dos *benchmarks* são feitos para mostrar um lado da coisa, uma implementação usa um recurso que dá uma vantagem e a outra não usa. Não estou defendendo nada aqui a não ser que essas comparações costumam ser só instrumentos de marketing. Existem testes sérios e que mostram a realidade, e eles possuem explicações do porquê aquele resultado.

Answer (score 14):

### Não Considere Desempenho

Resolvi colocar uma resposta, porém é preciso antecipar que respostas para esse tipo de pergunta vão acabar se baseando na experiência de cada um com a linguagem. Por exemplo, se a pessoa só trabalho com projetos simples em PHP ou se trabalhou com versões antigas, ou se não teve oportunidade de migrar de um sistema em PHP para outra linguagem ou vice-versa.

Qualquer tentativa de se fazer um comparativo de desempenho precisará de parâmetros que podem ser questionáveis, que podem beneficiar ou não uma característica da linguagem. No final, existem ferramentas que podem pré-compilar o código, podem otimizar o código, podem usar um comando ao invés de outro, etc. Dessa forma, o escopo da pergunta deveria dar esse foco, mas isso não está especificado.

Como exemplo para minha argumentação, posso citar um site chamado [CodeFights](https://codefights.com) onde o objetivo é resolver problemas onde as pessoas usam diversas linguagens diferentes e o resultado é que você aprende várias técnicas diferentes para fazer uma mesma coisa. Como a pontuação dos desafios é baseado no tamanho do código fonte, você percebe que mesmo tenho algo bastante otimizado muitas vezes fica ilegível ou dificulta o entendimento e nem sempre o código menor é o mais eficiente ou tem melhor desempenho, é apenas o código com menos linhas. É claro que existe um parâmetro de tempo de execução mínimo, porém o ranking acaba sendo feito pela quantidade de código escrito.

Se ao invés de usar o tamanho, o site utilizasse o desempenho para fazer o ranking acabaria tendo o mesmo problema de legibilidade ou de flexibilidade para deixar a solução do problema mais genérica, etc. O que quero dizer com isso é que não podemos fixar apenas uma característica de uma linguagem para fazer um julgamento dela.

Voltando ao PHP, é preciso saber que a linguagem não nasceu para solucionar problemas de desempenho, no meu entendimento. Ela nasceu com o objetivo de ser uma linguagem que pudesse ser fácil de entender e fácil de construir um site dinâmico de forma a simplificar tanto o código como a instalação em um servidor. Por esse motivo ela se tornou popular. Mas quando você junta uma linguagem fácil e flexível com a preguiça do programador, os prazos curtos de entrega, com as fases normais do desenvolvimento que caem no "primeiro funcionar, depois funcionar direito, depois funcionar direito e rápido", normalmente os projetos param na primeira fase e a culpa acaba ficando com a linguagem.

Eu entendo que os pontos fortes do PHP, embora se saiba que a versão mais recente teve muitas melhorias de execução do código, não tem foco principal no desempenho. Os pontos fortes estão ligados a ampla base de código, frameworks, exemplos, comunidade, componentes prontos, conectividade com banco de dados, tempo do ciclo de desenvolvimento tanto para novas funções como para manutenção entre outras características tão importantes como desempenho.

Colocando respostas aos questionamentos da pergunta:

> Acredito eu que, quando dizem que o PHP não se foca em seu desempenho,
>   seria em comparação a outras linguagens/tecnologias?

É provável que sim. A linguagem em si não gera um código lento. Apenas se fala em desempenho quando essa característica é essencial para o projeto. Para justificar um pouco mais a resposta, basta saber que um projeto que faz acesso a um banco de dados terá o tempo de acesso ao banco muito maior que o tempo de execução do código PHP, dessa forma uma melhoria no código ou trocar por um código em outra linguagem não vai fazer o tempo de acesso ao banco de dados diminuir.

> Isso seria sobre o PHP ser uma linguagem interpretada?

Sempre que comparar algo interpretado com algo compilado, a chance do interpretado ter mais desempenho é bem pequena.

> Somente o PHP ou todas as linguagens interpretadas ou correlacionadas?

De acordo com a argumentação que eu coloquei, se você tirar o aspecto da compilação e comparar apenas linguagens interpretadas, o desempenho vai depender do runtime e nesse caso, cada um vai ter seu desempenho determinado quando você definir o código a ser executado. De maneira geral os que se faz é rodar vários tipos de testes e fazer um média, tendo como final uma pontuação que pode dar uma ideia, porém não dever ser único determinante.

Existe um site interessante chamado [The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/). Você pode ver o comparativo de várias linguagens para tomar uma decisão baseado no código que foi testado. É bem interessante.

Considerando essa argumentação, a resposta para a sua pergunta seria não considerar o desempenho do PHP como única característica quando fizer algum tipo de avaliação, seja em forma de pesquisa ou para a escolha de uso em um projeto.

Comment: Pagotti, antemão agradeço sua resposta, gostei dos apontamentos quanto as 3 questões. Sobre alguns pontos que colocou em questão: "...vão acabar se baseando na experiência de cada um com a linguagem...", "...Dessa forma, o escopo da pergunta deveria dar esse foco, mas isso não está especificado..." O intuito da pergunta foi exatamente essas 3 questões, procurando uma explicação do porque dessas citações sobre o desempenho aparecerem, e jamais em comparar experiência com linguagem, comparação entre linguagens e muito menos opinião.

Comment: Interessante. O php em média chega a ser mais "veloz" do que outras linguagens web pelo que foi apresentado no site The Computer... que você postou.

Comment: A ideia é saber motivos técnicos mesmo, que acho que foram alcançados pelo Woss e sua resposta sobre as 3 questões. Agradeço participar ! +1

Comment: PHP rules! XD... Ótima resposta.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho mas a ideia não é a competição por desempenho, e sim entender o porque dizem isso, se é porque a linguagem em certo cenário, atinge aquele limite dela.

Comment: Sim... @RBZ eu entendi. Foi só um comentário. =)

Comment: É muito difícil conseguir criar uma pergunta dessa forma, sobre algo que precisa de uma enorme precisão desse ponto "comparativo não-comparativo". Mas fiquei feliz com o resultado até agora ! rs

Comment: @RBZ você foi muito bem nessa pergunta. É difícil mesmo.