# Qual é a diferença entre website e aplicação web?

Tags: aplicação-web

Fala-se que são diferentes. Qual a diferença entre um website e uma aplicação web (aplicativo web, web application)?

P.S.: Tem no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application)

Comment: Curiosamente no SOen foi fechada como primariamente baseada em opiniões

Comment: No fim, é tudo a mesma coisa e basicamente para o mesmo propósito, na "minha opinião".

Comment: Num diagrama de Venn, será que (website(aplicação web))?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Website é um conteúdo de páginas expostas publicamente de interação com o usuário em geral indexadas por mecanismos de busca com **conteúdo institucional, informativo** e de interação limitada às páginas ali existentes e eventualmente algum contato com o servidor. A páginas podem ser geradas dinamicamente, mas não deve ter dinamicidade grande no uso. O usuário costuma ser uma pessoa.

[Aplicação web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187344/101) usa tecnologias web (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.) para criar uma aplicação interativa com o usuário. Em geral é feito com um *login* e há um sistema de informações completo por de trás, incluindo um banco de dados. Mesmo em casos mais abertos é comum que a aplicação web permita operações típicas de uma aplicação desktop ou mobile. São cadastros, jogos, processadores, etc. Em geral eles possuem **tarefas específicas** que o usuário deve fazer, possivelmente com frequência. Muitas vezes esse usuário não é uma pessoa (ainda que seja uma pessoa usando).

Este é o tipo de coisa que não é tão fácil definir o que é, e é muito fácil esquecer de um pequeno detalhe que descaracteriza o pensamento (li várias coisas antes de responder e todas tem um furo na sua definição ou são muito vagas), mas você costuma saber o que é quando está na frente de um ou outro.

Nem sempre é fácil definir claramente o que é, por exemplo, aqui mesmo para quem chega e vê o Q&A é um website. Se essa pessoa começa interagir, participar da comunidade, aí está usando uma aplicação. E é o mesmo artefato de software.

Eu diria que se você faz algo que deveria ser desktop ou mobile, mas por questão de mobilidade ou porque só sabe fazer web preferiu fazer assim, então é uma aplicação web :)

Outro critério talvez seja a questão de precisar estar com conteúdo totalmente público (website) ou não, precisar ser indexado (website) ou não.

Se você acessa tanto pela web, como pelo desktop ou mobile, isto tende ser uma aplicativo, certo?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você caracterizaria o [google.com](https://www.google.com) como um website ou uma aplicação web? É claro que o Google hoje em dia é bem mais complexo. Me limito à página de pesquisa.

Comment: Então, é complicado definir. Talvez site por causa da baixa interação, porque ele dá uma informação e acabou.

Answer (score 5):

Um website ou simplesmente site é um conjunto de páginas WEB com informações diversas que tem o intuito praticamente de informar ou expôr alguma informação. Os exemplos mais comuns são os sites institucionais, desenvolvidos especificamente para empresas.

No caso das aplicações WEB a situação é muito diferente, uma aplicação WEB funciona como uma espécie de sistema, podemos até dizer que esses dois termos são sinônimos. Em uma aplicação WEB você pode realizar muito mais ações do que em um site normal. Em uma aplicação WEB é possível, por exemplo, cadastrar informações em um banco de dados e interagir com eles de muitas outras formas através de relatórios ou processos automatizados. O grande foco de uma aplicação WEB é solucionar um problema utilizando a programação para isso. Utilizar uma aplicação WEB é sem dúvida uma ótima opção já que ela conta com inúmeras vantagens como, por exemplo, o fato de estar disponível em qualquer lugar a qualquer hora.

Fonte: http://www.scriptcaseblog.com.br/diferenca-site-aplicacao-web/

Comment: Referência: http://www.scriptcaseblog.com.br/diferenca-site-aplicacao-web/