# Como imprimir de uma aplicação web em uma impressora local com C#?

Tags: c#, web-service, webforms, wcf, impressão

Preciso programar em web alguns recursos que realizam **impressão local**, onde são enviados textos e comandos para uma equipamento específico **sem a interação do usuário**. Por exemplo a emissão de etiquetas em equipamentos Zebra e Argox e impressão de cupons **não fiscais** em impressoras Bematech MP20.

**Qual a maneira mais eficiente para solucionar essa questão com C#?**

A única possibilidade que pensei foi criar uma aplicação de apoio para ser instalada no desktop, porém não estou seguro, seriam duas possibilidades:

1) Desenvolver uma aplicação como serviço WCF instalada no desktop e fazer a chamada da aplicação web. (Creio que nesse caso teria que haver configuração de firewall e direcionamento de porta, para permitir o acesso e isso não seria pratico devido ao volume de usuários acessando de ambientes diversos)

2) Criar um serviço (ASMX) no servidor e uma aplicação desktop que periodicamente consulte o serviço para verificar se existe atividade à realizar, então realiza a tarefa localmente. (Porém me preocupa o quanto esse serviço vai ficar ocupado mesmo quando na há impressão)

Vocês acham viável alguma dessas opções? Como vocês resolveriam?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O lado de servidor você pode fazer como quiser desde que ele sirva as informações que precisa do jeito que precisa. Particularmente eu evito fazer web porque ela tem desvantagens. Pegou moda as pessoas quererem que seja web. Fazer web tem a vantagem para [websites](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236208/101), em alguns casos bem mais raros do que as pessoas imaginam pode ser útil para aplicações, mas em geral a experiência com o usuário é prejudicada e não é boa ideia. Infelizmente parece algo que ninguém dá bola mais. O desempenho de servir por HTTP não é bom.

O lado do cliente realmente precisa fazer algo que tenha acesso total ao computador e deve ser uma aplicação desktop. Até pode fazer a aplicação rodar no navegador e uma auxiliar desktop, mas é gambiarra e raramente se justifica. A experiência do usuário sofrerá.

Pessoalmente eu não usaria WCF, prefiro usar TCP direto para comunicar com o servidor. Se quer fazer web no servidor mesmo então comunique por HTTP. Acho o WCF um trambolhão difícil de lidar, lento e pesado, mas eu prefiro o WCF bem feito por TCP do que aplicação web.

Configurar firewall não é problema, pode ser feito até programaticamente, eu não deixaria de fazer algo melhor pra vida toda porque dará um trabalhinho extra uma vez. Não entendo porque as pessoas botaram na cabeça que isto é um problema.

Mesmo que opte por fazer HTTP, eu usaria o ASP.NET Core ou pelo menos o ASP.NET MVC, não iria de ASP.NET clássico em hipótese alguma, ele é obsoleto. O MVC também o é, mas é recente.

Se fizer do jeito correto não haverá problemas em sobrecarga de processamento. Pode fazer sem susto ele verifica periodicamente. OU pode fazer no servidor uma sistema de assinatura que o servidor notifica quando tiver algo relevante para os clientes assinantes. Depende do volume de cada coisa e a necessidade de agilidade em ter as novidades, um ou outro pode ser melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Eu participei de diversos projetos utilizando estrutura parecida, mas as impressoras estavam no lado do servidor..
Sistemas onde eu tinha uma aplicação ASP.NET e essa aplicação realizava impressões em impressoras Zebra, inclusive tenho o framework pronto para a impressão caso necessite, posso colocar no Github.

O que eu fiz foi criar um WebService e publicar o mesmo no servidor onde a impressora está instalada, lembre-se que o WebService (ASMX) rodando no IIS (Application Pool) deverá ter permissões para realizar a impressão, esse foi um dos problemas, daí colocamos um usuário com permissões no ApplicationPool do IIS do WebService para realizar a impressão.

Sendo assim na chamada **Print** do `[WebMethod]` recebia como parâmetro o nome da impressora.

A aplicação roda à alguns anos e nunca tivemos problemas, para o projeto em questão foi a melhor solução, onde tínhamos mais de 10 impressoras Zebra instaladas no servidor.

Comment: Sua situação me parece inversa ao do colega, apesar de válida a solução. Acredito que a impressora dele deve estar no lado cliente, e não no servidor como a sua.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi, e entendo o impasse dele de ter que ficar instalando App's  locais no lado do cliente em função das impressoras.. situação um pouco delicada mesmo.

Comment: sim, só vi algo funcionando dessa forma utilizando activeX, que na situação realizava impressões em ECF.

Comment: Isso Mesmo a Impressora está do lado do Cliente, e a questão é que muitos desses clientes não tem um tecnico para administrar a rede, e usam dos mais vairados tipos de roteadores na infra local complicando se for publicado um serviço local. Continuo na Dúvida ainda!