# É possível criar um site sem linguagem de marcação?

Tags: javascript, html, linguagem-de-marcação

É possível criar um site sem nenhuma linguagem de marcação, só de programação, por exemplo JavaScript? Em linhas gerais, como?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, mas não faz o menor sentido.

Veja bem, faz um mínimo, e até gosto da ideia em [aplicação web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236208/101), mas para um site que precisa ser usado em condições universais da web, que precisa de indexação por mecanismos de busca, não é viável.

Carrega o arquivo JS e vai trazendo tudo por ele, provavelmente via AJAX, aí o *script* vai montando o [DOM "na mão"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101), ou seja, vai colocando o conteúdo, a formatação, tudo nos objetos do documento. Em vez de marcar o que deseja, você vai programar o que deseja de forma imperativa. Assim como é possível acessar tudo o que está no documento com JS pode manipulá-lo também, pode criar novos nós e ir montando a página.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Um site web é simplesmente um arquivo que um servidor remoto responde via uma requisição HTTP e que é renderizado pelo browser, então tenho algumas ideias:

0. Use um formato MIME de retorno diferente de HTML, mas que todo browser entenda e mostre, como "text/plain". Faça elementos gráficos com ASCII Art! Tome cuidado com o formato do arquivo, ou ele será simplesmente baixado ([html - content-type of text-plain causes browser to download of file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660578/946814)
   )
1. Utilize apenas o elemento `<canvas>`, e use a API de desenho 2D para fazer o site como quiser! Eu fiz um Game of Life assim em https://all-life.glitch.me/, embora eu tenha colocado um mínimo de marcação pra outras coisas ([código](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/all-life?path=index.html%3A1%3A0)).
2. Utilize uma *outra* linguagem de programação como C, usando OpenGL/WebGL para  a parte gráfica, e que compile para [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts). Talvez, por baixo dos panos ele use uma linguagem de marcação, mas quem vai parar pra ler assembly?