# Um programa desktop pode ser considerado client-side?

Tags: terminologia, aplicação-desktop, lado-do-servidor, lado-do-cliente

Sempre quando eu escuto/leio sobre *server-side* e *client-side* é referente a aplicações web, mas estes termos podem ser aplicados para programas *desktop*? Por exemplo se tenho uma aplicativo que consome um *web-service* ou até mesmo um Notepad (*offline*) posso considerá-los *client-side*, ou esta nomenclatura é apenas para aplicações web?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quaisquer aplicações de qualquer tipo que sirva para acessar algo que é servido externamente à aplicação "principal" pode ser considerado um cliente, não precisa estar nem em outra máquina.

O Outlook é uma aplicação desktop, certo? Ele é um cliente de e-mail. O navegador é um cliente HTTP que renderiza páginas e ele é desktop.

Acho que uma aplicação que não faz comunicação com outra coisa não deveria ser chamada de cliente, mas dá o que pensar. Uma aplicação que acessa um arquivo está sendo servida pelo menos pela *file system*, portanto ela é cliente da FS, certo? No mínimo é cliente dessa API.

Uma aplicação não precisa ser cliente de apenas uma coisa. E não precisa toda ela ser cliente de algo, só alguma parte dela.

Um computador que roda em uma rede e pega informações de algum lugar é um cliente de rede, certo? Não precisa sequer ser aplicação para chamarmos de cliente.

O conceito de cliente e servidor é ortogonal ao que a aplicação faz no geral. Algo nela é cliente de algo externo que fornece o que ela precisa.

Se tudo o que importa à aplicação é o acesso externo então podemos até dizer que a a aplicação é um cliente de forma geral.

Se você tiver uma [aplicação web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187344/101) que carrega no seu navegador e a partir daí não acessa mais nada externo, ela é um cliente? Do que?

Termos existem para explicar um conceito adotado. Se ele é irrelevante em certa situação, não tem porque usar o termo. Se vai usar o termo tem que entender completamente o que ele é, porque comunicação errada é pior que não comunicação, em grande parte das vezes, e em geral [a pessoa só sabe tarde demais se importa ou não](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Informação útil: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).